# Replace/Show content at a specific time and day using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am creating a radio station website. What I am trying to do is change the "thumbnail" of the current show on-air, and change the text and times of the upcoming 2 shows. I have checked the internet for some code that I understand. I have amended it, but now I am having challenges;

1. After defining the variables, I am unable to replace the img in the div. The "new" img does not appear at all, even though it is a specific time and day. In actual fact, it is as if nothing has happened.
2. I want to "refresh" the code every hour. By that I mean set an interval every hour. Challenge here is, I do not know where and how to go about doing this.

Here is my code;

```js
    var rightNow = new Date();
    var day = rightNow.getDay();
    var hour = rightNow.getHours();
    var minute = rightNow.getMinutes();
    var onAir = document.getElementsByClassName("onAirThumbnail");
    var nextShow = document.getElementsByClassName("nextHost");
    var nextTime = document.getElementsByClassName("nextTime");
    var followingShow = document.getElementsByClassName("followingHost");
    var followingTime = document.getElementsByClassName("followingTime");
    if (day === 6) {
        if ((hour == 13 && minute >= 0) || (hour == 15 && minute <= 59)) {
            $(onAir).src = "../img/urban_top_30.jpg";
            $(nextShow).innerHTML = "The Pass Out";
            $(nextTime).innerHTML = "13h00";
            $(followingShow).innerHTML = "The Plug Point";
            $(followingTime).innerHTML = "16h00";
        }
    }
```

```html
        <div class="row">
            <div id="stream">
                <h7 class="onAir"><strong>ON AIR</strong></h7><br>
                <img src="img/jam-avenue.jpg" onload="this.width/=2.5;" class="onAirThumbnail"><br>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">LISTEN LIVE</button><br>
                <div id="upNextTable">
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th><h8><strong>UP NEXT</strong></h8></th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="nextHost">Joey Drumz</td>
                            <td class="nextTime">22h00</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="followingHost">The First Impresssion</td>
                            <td class="followingTime">01h00</td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody><!-- end table body -->
                    </table><!-- end table -->
                </div><!-- end table div -->
            </div><!-- end stream div -->
        </div><!-- end div row -->
```

I know that this is a lot to ask, so I kindly request someone who has the patience and willingness to share their knowledge in assisting me.

Comment: You're quite badly mixing your jquery and javascript.  Remove all the $() code as you're calling js methods on jquery objects, eg change  `$(onAir).src=` to just `onAir.src=`.  Next, learn to use the console - it will be reporting errors (press F11 and go through the various tabs).  Include any error messages here if the above doesn't help.

Comment: @freedomn-m, thanks for you input. It helped a lot. I have managed to gt the code working. However, I still have challenges.